# SSLException: Connection reset with SharePoint graph API - file upload

Tags: ssl, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sites

I'm trying to develop a put method to create file on Sharepoint using graph API. Creating an upload session allow to upload files from 4Mo to 60Mo. I created this session and obtain a response which looks like this.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "uploadUrl": "https://url_for_uploading_file",
  "expirationDateTime": "2015-01-29T09:21:55.523Z"
}
```

Based on the documentation, I have to retrieve the uploadUrl and send my file.
https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/graph/api/driveitem-createuploadsession?view=graph-rest-1.0

I created a method that receives the request, the upload url and my token. This method allow to set httpPut params.

```
public SharePointDocumentResponseModel putFileRequest(SharePointDocumentByNameRequest request,
                                                      String token) throws IOException {
    SharePointDocumentResponseModel returnValue = new SharePointDocumentResponseModel();
    filePath = request.getFilePath();
    fileContent = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(new File(request.getFilePath()));
    byte[][] fileArrays = Utils.splitChunks(fileContent);
    int size = fileContent.length;
    long chunkSize = Constants.MAX_FILE_SPLIT;
    int numberOfChunks = (int) (size / chunkSize);
    int minRange = 0;
    int maxRange = 0;
    int count = 0;
    SortedMap<Integer,Integer> ranges = new TreeMap<>();


    // TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[]{new X509TrustManager() {
    //    public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
    //        return null;
    //    }
    //    public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
    //    }
    //    public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
    //    }
    // }};


    System.out.println("number of chunks " + (numberOfChunks+1));
    for(int i = 0; i <= numberOfChunks; i++) {
        maxRange += chunkSize;
        if(maxRange < size) {
            ranges.put(minRange, maxRange);
        } else {
            ranges.put(minRange, size);
        }
        minRange = maxRange + 1;
    }


    CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
    try {
        HttpPut httpPut = new HttpPut(String.valueOf(request.getUploadUrl()));
        httpPut.setHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
        httpPut.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/json;charset=UTF-8");
        //httpPut.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        httpPut.setHeader("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
        httpPut.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
        // Install the all-trusting trust manager

    // try {
    //    SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
    //    sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new SecureRandom());
    //    HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
    // } catch (Exception e) {
    //    e.printStackTrace();
    // }

        // splitter le fichier
        for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> range: ranges.entrySet()) {
            int step = range.getValue() - range.getKey();
            //httpPut.setHeader("Content-Range",
            //        "bytes " + range.getKey() + "-" + range.getValue() + "/" + fileContent.length);
            httpPut.setHeader("Content-Range",
                    "bytes " + range.getKey() + "-" + range.getValue() + "/" + Constants.CHUNK_SIZE);

            InputStreamEntity inputStreamEntity =
                    new InputStreamEntity(
                            new ByteArrayInputStream(fileArrays[count]),
                            fileContent.length
                    );
            count++;
            //inputStreamEntity.setChunked(true);
            httpPut.setEntity(inputStreamEntity);
            System.out.println("\nSending 'PUT' request to URL : " + request.getUploadUrl());
            System.out.println("Executing request : " + httpPut.getRequestLine());

            try (CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpPut)) {
                System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
                System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
                System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()));
                //returnValue = gson.fromJson(response.getEntity(), SharePointDocumentResponseModel.class);
            }
        }
        //InputStreamEntity inputStreamEntity = new InputStreamEntity(
        //        new FileInputStream(file), -1, ContentType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM);

    } finally {
        httpclient.close();
    }
    return returnValue;
}
```

At this stage the return value has not been set. I obtain a SSL Exception and a connection reset.
I tried to add a trustAllCerts TrustManager array object to solve this issue but the exception is also thrown.
On my library a temporary document is created.

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection reset
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:127)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:321)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:264)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:259)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.handleException(SSLSocketImpl.java:1314)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppInputStream.read(SSLSocketImpl.java:839)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.streamRead(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:137)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.fillBuffer(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:153)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.readLine(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:280)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:138)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:56)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:259)
    at org.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:163)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPoolProxy.receiveResponseHeader(CPoolProxy.java:157)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:273)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:125)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:272)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:108)
    at fr.dsidiff.api.sharepoint.request.HttpRequest.putFileRequest(HttpRequest.java:363)
    at fr.dsidiff.api.sharepoint.service.impl.DocumentServiceImpl.uploadWithSession(DocumentServiceImpl.java:39)
    at fr.dsidiff.api.sharepoint.SharePointCaller.getResponse(SharePointCaller.java:410)
    at fr.dsidiff.api.sharepoint.SharePointCaller.createDocument(SharePointCaller.java:363)
    at fr.dsidiff.api.sharepoint.tests.DocumentCallTest.createDocumentByNameBigFile(DocumentCallTest.java:51)
    at fr.dsidiff.api.sharepoint.tests.DocumentCallTest.main(DocumentCallTest.java:29)
    Suppressed: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
        at java.base/java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:110)
        at java.base/java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:150)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketOutputRecord.encodeAlert(SSLSocketOutputRecord.java:81)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:352)
        ... 27 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:186)
    at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:140)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.read(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:448)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.bytesInCompletePacket(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:68)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readApplicationRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1104)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppInputStream.read(SSLSocketImpl.java:823)
    ... 23 more
```

Answer (score 0):

It's nothing to do with Microsoft Graph API you may want to open MS Graph Explorer or POSTMAN, test it out the above API will work. SSL/JDK related error here. Here's the related bug on this - https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8241372

Comment: To isolate the issue, you can try making the same API call using MS Graph Explorer or POSTMAN and see still if you can repro the issue or not. If still there is an issue, then i agree API end you can point out. If you failed to repro the issue, then look at the SSL/JDK as updated above.

Comment: I didn't solve this issue already. I put this in standby. I'll give the solution when i'll find it.

Comment: Wonderful @davidvera. Please do so, good to learn and good for community too..!!

Comment: @Dev
Running some testing using C# and Javascript show the same SSL failures when sending a largish number of requests over a short timespan, e.g. 1 request per 5ms will consistently result in SSL errors after ~900 requests

Comment: hmm, i would suggest you can try the official Graph SDK for Java (the latest one) and see if you can repro the issue. If yes, consider filing the request in the issues section, so that it can be handled; thats the benefit you get with the official SDKs.